# Tensorflow Object Detection API no train.py file

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I've correctly installed Tensorflow Object Detection API according to the provided documentation. However, when I need to train my network there is no train.py file in the research/object_detection directory.
Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

Comment: You can show the loss with this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039122/11921531).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the newest merge the train and eval moved to legacy dir. You can go to a previous version if you work with a tutorial.

Answer (score 8):

For some clarification, as aforementioned by Derek Chow, it seems the train and evaluation python scripts were recently (~6 days ago) moved into the 'legacy' directory. 
Assuming you wanted to continue using the old way..

If one was beginning training by calling:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

One would know begin training by calling:

```
python legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

Comment: Thank you. The point is that I run the model_main new script but it seems that it does not show the loss on the console.
Using the previous script (train.py) I could clearly see on the console something like:

step n -- loss: 2.5312
step n+1 --loss: 2.5310

Answer (score 6):

You should refer to [Running locally](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md#running-locally)
 section on the tutorial page.

Here is the sample configuration:

```
#From the tensorflow/models/research/ directory
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH={path to pipeline config file}
MODEL_DIR={path to model directory}
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=50000
NUM_EVAL_STEPS=2000
python object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
    --num_eval_steps=${NUM_EVAL_STEPS} \
    --alsologtostderr
```

and to run tensorboard:

```
tensorboard --logdir=${MODEL_DIR}
```

Comment: are you saying that model_main.py does both train and evaluation? What if I would like to run them separately because I need to supervise the learning phase?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [legacy](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/legacy) train and evaluation scripts, but we recommend using model_main.

Comment: Is it normal that the new model_main script does not show the loss on the console? Or maybe there's something wrong in mt tf config?

Comment: You should see event files being generated by model_main. Visualize these in tensorboard to see the training loss.

Comment: That's true Derek, but tf events are generated not at each step. They are record every 50-70 steps. This is why print the loss value on the console is useful.

Comment: Hello Derek, where can we modify to show loss value on the console as before when using model_main.py? Thank you and thank you, Giacomo, for asking this question.

Comment: I have the same question about the loss, still waiting for anyone's answer.